# Pandas indexed dataframe display: use top left empty box

Tags: python, pandas, display

Is there a way to put text in the top left box of a dataframe display? Does that field have a name? See below:

```
import pandas as pd
raw_data = {'Regiment': ['Nighthawks', 'Raptors'], 
    'Company': ['1st', '2nd'], 
    'preTestScore': [4, 24],
    'postTestScore': [25, 94]}
pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['Regiment', 'Company', 'preTestScore', 'postTestScore']).set_index('Regiment')
```

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. That space is used for the name of the columns. It can be filled in by doing

```
df.columns.name = 'your name'
```